# s3cmd nodename nor servname provided, or not known

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, s3cmd

I'm trying to access objects from my S3 bucket with s3cmd with path style urls. This is no problem with the Java SDK like.

```
s3Client.setS3ClientOptions(S3ClientOptions.builder()
            .setPathStyleAccess(true).build());
```

I want to do the same with s3cmd. I have set this up in my s3conf file:

```
host_base = s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com
host_bucket = s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/%(bucket)s
```

This works for bucket listing with:

```
$ s3cmd ls 
2016-08-24 12:36  s3://test
```

When trying to list all objects of a bucket I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/usr/local/bin/s3cmd", line 2919, in <module>
rc = main()
 File "/usr/local/bin/s3cmd", line 2841, in main
rc = cmd_func(args)
  File "/usr/local/bin/s3cmd", line 120, in cmd_ls
subcmd_bucket_list(s3, uri)
 File "/usr/local/bin/s3cmd", line 153, in subcmd_bucket_list
response = s3.bucket_list(bucket, prefix = prefix)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/S3/S3.py", line 297, in bucket_list
for dirs, objects in self.bucket_list_streaming(bucket, prefix, recursive, uri_params):
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/S3/S3.py", line 324, in  bucket_list_streaming
response = self.bucket_list_noparse(bucket, prefix, recursive, uri_params)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/S3/S3.py", line 343, in bucket_list_noparse
response = self.send_request(request)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/S3/S3.py", line 1081, in send_request
conn = ConnMan.get(self.get_hostname(resource['bucket']))
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/S3/ConnMan.py", line 192, in get
conn.c.connect()
 File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 836, in connect
self.timeout, self.source_address)
 File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 557, in create_connection
for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
 gaierror: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that there is no other issue with your configuration, the value that you used for "host_bucket" is wrong.

It should be:

```
host_bucket = %(bucket)s.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com
```

or

```
host_bucket = s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com
```

The second one will for "path style" to be used. But, if you are using amazon s3 and the first host_bucket value that I propose, s3cmd will automatically use dns-based or path-based buckets depending of what characters you are using in your bucket name.

Is it a particular reason why you would want to only use path-based style?